# How to update spring framework version in maven project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

My project has 4 spring boot applications inside it. I want to update the spring framework version of all the 4 modules to 5.3.17 from 4.3.12.RELEASE. I have already updated the spring boot version of the project in the parent pom(reference-pom)(spring-boot version 2.6.4). The project's pom.xml is below . Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>car</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.myproject.cs.car</groupId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.3.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>car</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myproject.cs</groupId>
        <artifactId>reference-pom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modules>
        <module>batchretriever</module>
        <module>dataloader</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>appservices</module>
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>war</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging>war</packaging>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--
            Be cautious when adding dependencies here. They get adding to ever child POM.
            Consider importing in each child what is actually needed or add a dependency
            management section here for common dependencies that are not in in the
            Reference POM.
        -->

        <!--Application Dependencies Below-->

        <!--Test Dependencies Below-->

        <!--Provided, Runtime, and Optional Dependencies Below-->
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The reference-pom is,

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version> <!--August 2022-->
    </parent>
<properties>
        <!--Recommended Properties Below-->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

        <!--Recommended Application Dependency Versions Below-->
        <commons-lang3.version>3.7</commons-lang3.version> <!--August 2018-->
        <apache-poi.version>3.17</apache-poi.version> <!--April 2019 -->
        <jooq.version>3.11.5</jooq.version>
        <jooq.modelmapper.version>1.1.2</jooq.modelmapper.version> <!--January 2018-->
        <jjwt.version>0.9.0</jjwt.version> <!--July 2018-->
        <hapi-fhir.version>3.2.0</hapi-fhir.version><!--January 2018 -->
        <open-ehealth-ipf.version>3.4.1</open-ehealth-ipf.version><!--December 2017-->
        <springfox-swagger2.version>3.0.0</springfox-swagger2.version> <!--June 2018-->
        <selenium.version>3.8.1</selenium.version> <!--December 2017-->

        <!--Recommended Test Dependency Versions-->
        <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version> <!--September 2016-->

        <!--Recommended Provided, Runtime, and Optional Dependencies Below-->
        <oracle.driver.version>12.2.0.1</oracle.driver.version> <!--Should use what DEV Ops recommends-->
        <postgresql.version>42.2.0</postgresql.version> <!--January 2018-->
        <activemq-broker.version>5.16.3</activemq-broker.version>

        <!--Recommended Plugin Versions-->
        <!--
            Before adding a plugin version here check in the spring boot spring-boot-dependencies POM which is two parent POMs up to see if it already exists
            Parent POMs can be viewed by hitting F4 on the parent POM reference in the pom.xml file.  Follow the naming convention in there to override
            the version versus creating a new property.  It has been found that some of the Maven plugins are pretty old in the Spring Boot parent POM
           and their newer versions work better.
        -->
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-jar-plugin.version> <!--June 2016-->
        <maven-war-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-war-plugin.version> <!--September 2017-->
        <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.6.0</exec-maven-plugin.version> <!--March 2017-->
    </properties>

    <!--
        Anything in dependency management will NOT be automatically by a child POM.  The child POM should NOT include the version
        if it chooses to include one of these dependencies.  The version in this POM is the recommended version and that is the
        version the child POM receives by importing one of these dependencies.  However, if child POM needs to use an alternative
        version for a good technical reason then the child POM can override the version.
   -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Recommended Application Dependencies Below-->
            <!--Apache Commons Lang for helpful utility methods not included in core Java-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Apache POI for Java Excel Manipulation-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>${apache-poi.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Selenium for WebDriver for Web Browser Automation-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--JSON Web Token Support for the JVM-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--JOOQ-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jooq.pro</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--JOOQ meta-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jooq.pro</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--JOOQ code generation-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jooq.pro</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--JOOQ model mapper-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.modelmapper.extensions</groupId>
                <artifactId>modelmapper-jooq</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.modelmapper.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--HAPI FHIR-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
                <artifactId>hapi-fhir-base</artifactId>
                <version>${hapi-fhir.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
                <artifactId>hapi-fhir-utilities</artifactId>
                <version>${hapi-fhir.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
                <artifactId>hapi-fhir-structures-dstu3</artifactId>
                <version>${hapi-fhir.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
                <artifactId>hapi-fhir-server</artifactId>
                <version>${hapi-fhir.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
                <artifactId>hapi-fhir-client</artifactId>
                <version>${hapi-fhir.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Open eHealth Integration Platform-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openehealth.ipf</groupId>
                <artifactId>ipf-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${open-ehealth-ipf.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--Springfox Swagger-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Springfox Swagger Java Bean Validatiors-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
                <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Springfox Swagger UI-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!--Recommended Test Dependencies Below-->
            <!--Cucumber JUnit for Cucumber Tests-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--Cucumber Spring for Spring support in Cucumber-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--Recommended Provided, Runtime, and Optional Dependencies Below-->
            <!--Oracle Database Driver-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                <version>${oracle.driver.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--PostgresSQL Database Driver-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
                <version>${activemq-broker.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <!--
            This sets the versions of plugins to use.  The child POM will need to supply any additional configuration for the plugin.

            Plugins already managed in the spring-boot-dependencies parent POM do NOT need to be included here.  Only their version property
            needs to be overridden in the the properties section of this POM.

            The version in this POM is the recommended version is the recommended version and that is what the POM doing the import will receive.
            However, if the POM doing the import needs to use an alternative version for a good technical reason the it can be overridden in the
            POM doing the import.
       -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--Maven plugin for JOOQ code generation-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jooq.pro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>${jooq.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: Why all the overrides of the Spring Boot management? ! You are even mixing jars from different versions of a framework (Jackson). Upgrading Spring BOot also upgrades Spring.

Comment: After upgrading spring boot to 2.6.4 the spring version is still 4.3.12.RELEASE. There is no dependency for spring core or context or beans in the pom files.

Comment: Spring 2.6 wont even work with Spring 4.3. Probably one of your other dependencies is interfering with it (most likely I would suspect the `ipf-dependencies`) if that is build against Spring 4.3 you might not even be able to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Can't I override also? Override spring framework in ipf-depdendencies?

Comment: That depends on how it is managed, and **if** it actually supports something newer.