# Why spring context,aop,beans,expression version is not updating to 5.x version when I updated spring boot version to 2.6.4?

Tags: maven

Below is the result of  mvn depdendency:tree .I want to upgrade spring frame work version to 5.3.17. Please help, thanks in advance

```
 \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.2.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.4:runtime
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.4:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.10:runtime
[INFO]    \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO]       +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO]       \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
```

Comment: Please share your pom.xml.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624762/how-to-update-spring-framework-version-in-maven-project?noredirect=1#comment130040055_73624762

Comment: spring-boot 2.4.x brings spring-framework 5 dependencies (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1f535a6c556859b5ccd1e6ff3246b9410191444e/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L1711 )
Besides, you're overriding managed version and managed plugins which isn't recommended.